# Inheriting DataTemplate in WinRT

Tags: windows-runtime, datatemplate

I am using WinRT XAML. I am trying to create my own HirarchicalDataTemplate in WinRT. I inherited my class from DataTemplate.

```
public class HierarchicalDataTemplate : DataTemplate
{}
```

But when I try to initialize a new HierarchicalDataTemplate in my Page resources, it shows following error on compilation.

> HierarchicalDataTemplate does not contain a definition for 'Template'.

Any ideas how to resolve.

Comment: Have you tried porting one from Silverlight Toolkit? I was planning to do it at some point together with the TreeView control. It's in Silverlight4\Source\Controls\Data\HierarchicalDataTemplate.cs

Comment: The problem in WinRT is inheriting a class from DataTemplate. That leads to the above error. I hope HierarchicalDataTemplate from Silverlight toolkit also inherited from DataTemplate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The WinRT version of `DataTemplate` does not have a public `Template` property. The `ContentProperty` is specified as `Template`, so I tried changing that:

```
[ContentProperty(Name = "MyTemplate")]
```

However the error persists: the code generation tries to add an entry for the `Template` property all the same, from XamlTypeInfo.g.cs:

```
userType.AddMemberName("MyTemplate");
userType.AddMemberName("Template");
```

To use a different content property, we can either use a non `DataTemplate` subclass and define both `Template` and `ItemTemplate` of type `DataTemplate`; or continue to subclass `DataTemplate`, implement a dummy `Template` property, and use a separate `MyTemplate` property to host the actual content template. That might be usable at a push, but can't allow the template to be used in a `DataTemplate` type property.

Trying to get a `DataTemplate` subclass to work, I tried adding a `Template` property of `object` type:

```
public class HierarchicalDataTemplate : DataTemplate
{
    public object Template
    {
        get { return (object)GetValue(TemplateProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TemplateProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TemplateProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Template", typeof(object), typeof(HierarchicalDataTemplate), new PropertyMetadata(null));
    // ItemTemplate...
}
```

This works in the Visual Studio designer, but not at runtime:

```
<local:HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="t1">
    <TextBlock Text="SUCCESS" />
</local:HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

From [FrameworkTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.frameworktemplate) docs:

> FrameworkTemplate has a ContentPropertyAttribute that indicates that its XAML content property is named "Template". FrameworkTemplate doesn't define a property of that name, nor do its derived types that have a practical usage (ControlTemplate, DataTemplate). The content of a FrameworkTemplate is a root element that should be created when the template is applied, and isn't a conventional property in the object model. Content of a FrameworkTemplate is handled specially by the XAML parser when content is created from a template.

It doesn't look too hopeful.

Comment: Actually things seem to 'work' at runtime when subclassing without touching Template, and editing the generated XamlTypeInfo.g.cs - but not sure how to make that into a proper solution.

Answer (score 1):

I finally got round to port the `TreeView` control from Silverlight Toolkit yesterday, which wasn't too hard for non-data-bound use, but then I hit the same problem you had. My solution was to use a regular `DataTemplate` for `TreeView.ItemTemplate` and then modify the `HierarchicalDataTemplate` to derive from `FrameworkElement` instead of `DataTemplate` and I attached it to the `ItemTemplate` with an attached property (`DataTemplateExtensions.Hierarchy`). You can check the sample **[here](http://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/80e447e1edee#WinRTXamlToolkit.Sample/Views/Controls/TreeViewTestPage.xaml)**.

```
<xc:TreeView
    x:Name="tvDataBound"
    Grid.Row="1"
    Grid.Column="1"
    Style="{StaticResource TouchTreeViewStyle}"
    ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource TouchTreeViewItemStyle}">
    <xc:TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <data:DataTemplateExtensions.Hierarchy>
                <data:HierarchicalDataTemplate
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Children}" />
            </data:DataTemplateExtensions.Hierarchy>
            <StackPanel
                Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock
                    Text="{Binding Text}" />
                <Ellipse
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    Margin="5"
                    Width="10"
                    Height="10"
                    Fill="{Binding Brush}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
        <!-- Original implementation based on Silverlight Toolkit didn't work:
        <data:HierarchicalDataTemplate
            ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
            <StackPanel
                Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock
                    Text="{Binding Text}" />
                <Ellipse
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    Margin="5"
                    Width="10"
                    Height="10"
                    Fill="{Binding Brush}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </data:HierarchicalDataTemplate>-->
    </xc:TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</xc:TreeView>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would agree that this is a vexing problem and that this is a template you would really like to see. It does not appear as if you can actually inherit from `DataTemplate` and get it to work properly - many of the controls offered to you by WinRT do not support inheritance by the user program for multiple reasons (private constructors on data structures and voodoo like the `Template` property come to mind).

However, since it appears as if you are using the `HierarchicalDataTemplate` purely for a custom control, you actually do not need to inherit from `DataTemplate` at all because you have complete control over when the `DataTemplate` is harvested (you and only you can call `LoadContent()` on it to populate your control). Instead, your best option would be to create a custom class that has whatever extra data fields and behavior you need, and then a property that contains a `DataTemplate` that is referenced and instantiated. In fact, by using the `ContentProperty` attribute, you might even be able to skip the `ItemTemplate` property and the `DataTemplate`'s `Template` property and make it seem to your XAML users as if you *did* inherit from `DataTemplate`.